# mutableState VS mutableStateFlow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I'm confused, can someone explain to me, what's the main difference between those two? I'm having hard times understanding. mutableState was introduced with Jetpack Compose, and now my question is, should we use it in a View Model as a replacement for Mutabel State Flow? What are their purposes and main differences?

Comment: [Jetpack Compose MutableState schedules a recomposition of the composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState), MutableStateFlow does not. In other words, MutableStateFlow is generic state, MutableState is meant to be used with composables.

Comment: Flow is a great fit when the production of data needs to start/stop to match the observer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

mutableState is as you mentioned is part of the Jetpack Compose which acts as a trigger and observable data to trigger recomposition or update state of your ui. The composition depends on level of component that reads the value of `mutableState`

It depends on your logic to use mutableStateOf in your composable. It's simple update flag for Jetpack Compose.

On the other hand mutableStateFlow is something like RxJava' subjects where you can set and observe values and do multiple operations on it in a reactive way such as map, filter, set threading or handle errors using it.

```
myStateFlow.debounce(1000)
            .onStart {  }
            .catch { 
                
            }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Answer (score 15):

`MutableState` is for Jetpack Compose, `MutableStateFlow` is replacement for `MutableLiveData`, used inside `ViewModel`.