# When I change ViewModel var, Composable Doesn't Update in Kotlin + Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I change ViewModel variable, Composable Doesn't Update the View and I'm not sure what to do.

This is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object  {
        val TAG: String = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private val auth by lazy {
        Firebase.auth
    }

    var isAuthorised: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        setContent {
            HeroTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Menu(user)
                    } else {
                        AuthTools(auth, isAuthorised)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a a View Model:

```
class ProfileViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var profile: Profile? = null
    val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

    init {
        fetchProfile()
    }

    fun fetchProfile() {
        GlobalScope.async {
            getProfile()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getProfile() {
        user?.let {
            val docRef = firestore.collection("Profiles")
                .document(user.uid)

            return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
                docRef.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                        if (document != null) {
                            this.profile = getProfileFromDoc(document)
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a Composable View upon user autentication:

```
@Composable
fun Menu(user: FirebaseUser) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val ProfileVModel = ProfileViewModel()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

        ) {

        Text("Signed in!");


        ProfileVModel.profile?.let {
            Text(it.username);
        }

        Row(
            horizontalArrangement =  Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                context.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
            }) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Black,
                    text = "Sign out?",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When my Firestore method returns, I update the `profile` var, and "expect" it to be updated in the composable, here:

```
    ProfileVModel.profile?.let {
        Text(it.username);
    }
```

However, nothing is changing?

When I was adding firebase functions from inside composable, I could just do:

```
context.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
```

And it would update the view. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this from inside a ViewModel, since "context" is a Composable-specific feature?

I've tried to look up Live Data, but every tutorial is either too confusing or differs from my code. I'm coming from SwiftUI MVVM so when I update something in a ViewModel, any view that's using the value updates. It doesn't seem to be the case here, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That's almost the same as in Swift. You need to use states, as Remo already mentioned in his answer. Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) or this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile in view model should be State<*>

```
private val _viewState: MutableState<Profile?> = mutableStateOf(null)
val viewState: State<Profile?> = _viewState
```

In composable

```
ProfileVModel.profile.value?.let {
   Text(it.username);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did something like this: 
`private var _profile = MutableStateFlow<Profile?>(null)

val profile: MutableStateFlow<Profile?> get() = _profile`

Is there any major differences with what you answered vs the above code?

Comment: @Heron.F [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217911/13161449)

Answer (score 7):

#### Part 1: Obtaining a `ViewModel` correctly

On the marked line below you are setting your view model to a new `ProfileViewModel` instance on every recomposition of your `Menu` composable, which means your view model (and any state tracked by it) will reset on every recomposition. That prevents your view model to act as a view state holder.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Menu(user: FirebaseUser) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val ProfileVModel = ProfileViewModel() // <-- view model resets on every recomposition

    // ...
}
```

You can fix this by always obtaining your `ViewModel`s from the `ViewModelStore`. In that way the `ViewModel` will have the correct owner (correct lifecycle owner) and thus the correct lifecycle.
Compose has a helper for obtaining `ViewModel`s with the [`viewModel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewmodel) call.

This is how you would use the call in your code

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Menu(user: FirebaseUser) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val ProfileVModel: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()
    // or this way, if you prefer
    // val ProfileVModel = viewModel<ProfileViewModel>()

    // ...
}
```

See also [`ViewModels in Compose`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-arch#viewmodel) that outlines the fundamentals related to `ViewModel`s in Compose.

> Note: if you are using a DI (dependency injection) library (such as Hilt, Koin...) then you would use the helpers provided by the DI library to obtain `ViewModel`s.

#### Part 2: Avoid `GlobalScope` (unless you know exactly why you need it) and watch out for exceptions

As described in [Avoid Global Scope](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope) you should avoid using `GlobalScope` whenever possible. Android `ViewModel`s come with their own coroutine scope accessible through `viewModelScope`. You should also [watch out for exceptions](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#exceptions).

Example for your code

```kotlin
class ProfileViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // ...
    fun fetchProfile() {
        // Use .launch instead of .async if you are not using
        // the returned Deferred result anyway
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // handle exceptions
            try {
                getProfile()
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                // TODO: Log the failed attempt and/or notify the user
            }
        }
    }

    // make it private, in most cases you want to expose
    // non-suspending functions from VMs that then call other
    // suspend factions inside the viewModelScope like fetchProfile does
    private suspend fun getProfile() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

More coroutine best practices are covered in [Best practices for coroutines in Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices).

#### Part 3: Managing state in Compose

Compose tracks state through [`State<T>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State). If you want to manage state you can create [`MutableState<T>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState) instances with [`mutableStateOf<T>(value: T)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)), where the `value` parameter is the value you want to initialize the state with.

You could keep the state in your view model like this

```kotlin
// This VM now depends on androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class ProfileViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var profile: Profile? by mutableStateOf(null)
        private set
    // ...
}
```

then every time you would change the `profile` variable, composables that use it in some way (i.e. read it) would recompose.

However, if you don't want your view model `ProfileViewModel` to depend on the Compose runtime then there are other options to track state changes while not depending on the Compose runtime. From the documentation section [Compose and other libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#streams)

> Compose comes with extensions for Android's most popular stream-based
> solutions. Each of these extensions is provided by a different
> artifact:
>
> - `Flow.collectAsState()` **doesn't require extra dependencies**. (because it is part of `kotlinx-coroutines-core`)
> - `LiveData.observeAsState()` included in the `androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$composeVersion` artifact.
> - `Observable.subscribeAsState()` included in the `androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$composeVersion` or
>   > `androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava3:$composeVersion` artifact.
>
> These artifacts register as a listener and represent the values as a
> `State`. Whenever a new value is emitted, Compose recomposes those parts
> of the UI where that `state.value` is used.

This means that you could also use a `MutableStateFlow<T>` to track changes inside the `ViewModel` and expose it outside your view model as a `StateFlow<T>`.

```kotlin
// This VM does not depend on androidx.compose.runtime.* anymore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow

class ProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _profileFlow = MutableStateFlow<Profile?>(null)
    val profileFlow = _profileFlow.asStateFlow()

    private suspend fun getProfile() {
        _profileFlow.value = getProfileFromDoc(document)
    }
}
```

And then use [`StateFlow<T>.collectAsState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) inside your composable to get the `State<T>` that is needed by Compose.

> A general `Flow<T>` can also be collected as `State<T>` with [`Flow<T : R>.collectAsState(initial: R)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsState(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)), where the initial value has to be provided.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Menu(user: FirebaseUser) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val ProfileVModel: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()
    val profile by ProfileVModel.profileFlow.collectAsState()

    Column(
        // ...
    ) {
        // ...
        profile?.let {
            Text(it.username);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

To learn more about working with state in Compose see the documentation section on [Managing State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). This is fundamental information to be able to work with state in Compose and trigger recompositions efficiently. It also covers the fundamentals of [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting). If you prefer a coding tutorial here is the [code lab for State in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#0).

An introduction to handling the state as the complexity increases is in the video from Google about [Using Jetpack Compose's automatic state observation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmv2ug-wW4U).

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Very details!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `MutableStateFlow`.

a simple sample is described in this Medium article :

https://farhan-tanvir.medium.com/stateflow-with-jetpack-compose-7d9c9711c286